# Azure Logic App office 365 outlook connection issue

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am unable to create office 365 outlook connection in azure logic app.
It shows me following error-:
Create and authorize OAuth connection failed. Connection test uniqueness failed.

[image]

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

- One of the reasons you are receiving this is because the logic app doesn't recognize the connector to be unique and the connection name already exists.
- Try navigating to your resource group. Make sure you don't have an API connection the same as the one that you have created.
- You can also troubleshoot this using Developer tools. While entering your details and submitting the form, you will be returned with certain response codes. Depending on the response codes you can troubleshoot further.

Here is a similar issue that you can refer to [Connection test uniqueness failed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/625536/logic-app-error-connection-sap.html)

> If you are returned with 202 the issue is with the connection name being already in use, try deleting the already existing connections from your resource group and add again. By any means, if you receive 503, connection creation is no longer possible and you can raise a support ticket.

**NOTE:-** Make sure you are using a Work or School account and not a personal account.